# ideal in ring R is subgroup of additive group $R^+$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I was told that any ideal in a ring $R$ is a subgroup of the additive group $R^+$, I was also told that it is actually a normal subgroup. I am a bit skeptical about this, but cannot think of any contradictions for it. If this is true, does anyone have reference to a book on a proof of this, or know a proof for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Definitions), an ideal in a ring $R$ is a subgroup of the additive group $R^+=(R,+)$ that satisfies an absorbing property.

Since, by definition of ring, the additive group $R^+$ is abelian, every subgroup is normal.

Comment: Is the identity always in the ideal I

Comment: @PhilKing, the *additive* identity $0$ is!

Comment: Awesome, I almost see why it is true, One more question: How are we guaranteed that I is a subset of $R^+$?

Comment: By definition I is a subset of R, so does it just follow that I is a subset of $R^+$?

Comment: And how come we can say that an arbitrary ring R, has $R^+$ abelian?

Comment: @PhilKing $R$ and $R^+$ are the same set, $R^+$ is just notation for $(R,+)$.  And commutativity of addition is part of the axioms.